# How to add component AFTER rendering page

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

After migrating wicket to 1.5 I encounter this issue.
In Wicket 1.5 I (programmer before me) was adding JS and CSS reference in constructor and then component, simmilar to this:

```
    public abstract class PageTemplate extends WebPage implements IHeaderContributor {
        public BarePageTemplate() {
            this(null);
        }

        public BarePageTemplate(PageParameters params) {
            super(params);
            add(JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(ResourceMarker.class, "js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"));
            add(JavascriptPackageResource.getHeaderContribution(ResourceMarker.class, "js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"));
            [...]
            jGrowlMarker = new Label("jGrowlMarker"); // placeholder for jgrowl messages
            jGrowlMarker.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            jGrowlMarker.add(new JGrowlBehavior());
            add(jGrowlMarker);
        }
    }
```

In wicket 1.5 this is no longer possible. According to [migration guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5) I refactored this code into this:

```
     public abstract class PageTemplate extends WebPage implements IHeaderContributor {
        public BarePageTemplate() {
            this(null);
        }

    public BarePageTemplate(PageParameters params) {
        super(params);
        jGrowlMarker = new Label("jGrowlMarker"); // placeholder for jgrowl messages
        jGrowlMarker.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        jGrowlMarker.add(new JGrowlBehavior());
        add(jGrowlMarker);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"));
        response.renderJavaScriptReference(new CommonResourceRef("js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"));
[...]
}
}
```

This piece of code works, what I mean by that is that it includes those `js`. What causing me an issue is fact that right now my component (in this case jGrowlMarker) is rendering in page before page includes those js:

```
// jGrowl component

<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/pl.softq.commons.ui.resource.ResourceMarker/js/jquery-1.4.2.min-ver-65B352E1BA79F0E2A3B1E014BC2571AF.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./wicket/resource/pl.softq.commons.ui.resource.ResourceMarker/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min-ver-88A9784D8E08D25998F239E2D65F03D7.js"></script>
```

Because of that it doesn't work properly (I believe thats an issue). It tries to create jGrowl component but jGrowl.js is added after this component.
`[...]` symbolizes rest of my js and css refenreces (including jGrowl ones). I've tried to add  `super.renderHead(response)`; to `renderHead` but it also doesnt work (super.renderHead refers to empty one in `Component.class`).

So my question is: how to add component after `renderHead` initializes or how to add it inside `renderHead`.
I'm not an expert in wicket so if you need more piece of code, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the renderHead() method to JGrowlBehavior. This way it will contribute the dependencies first and then jgrowl.js itself.
If the dependencies are contributed by something else in the page too Wicket will detect this and contribute them just once.

In Wicket 6.x there are further improvements in this area. You can read http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-resource-management/